# Why does my button not trigger the form when in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-5

Ive created a boostratp modal, with 2 buttons. Both buttons are of the submit type and shall trigger the form which is wrapped around them. But this is not the case and I can't figure out why

This is my Code:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "accept") {
    echo "Acccepted";
} elseif (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "reject") {
    "Accepted";
}
}
?>

<<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#guest">
    <p>>Friend request from <b>guest</b></p>
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="guest">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Request from <b>guest</b></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Accept request?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <form action="test.php" method="post">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="accept" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="action" value="reject" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Reject</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="Username" value="guest">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</a>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ive tried wrapping the form around more stuff including the modal divs, but it still doesnt work.
I just want the buttons to submit a form, so that I can catch it in my PHP Block.

Comment: Most likely, because you nested the whole thing into a link - which is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: The link which opens the modal is wrapping the actual modal inside it - which makes no logical sense, and will also interefere with the form. Look at bit closer at the examples in the docs - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your form and modal are nested inside an anchor `(<a>)` tag. The anchor tag is designed to navigate to a different URL or a different part of the same page, not to submit a form. When you click the button, the anchor tag is likely interfering with the form submission.

To fix this issue, you should move the anchor tag so that it only wraps the text that should trigger the modal, not the modal itself. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
    <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#guest">
    <p>Friend request from <b>guest</b></p>
</a>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="guest">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Request from <b>guest</b></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Accept request?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form action="test.php" method="post">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="accept" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="action" value="reject" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Reject</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Username" value="guest">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this configuration, the anchor tag only wraps the text that should trigger the modal. The modal and the form are outside the anchor tag, so they should work as expected.

Hope this will fix your problem.

Thanks...